# Ruby: Filter Non-Integers from String

Tags: ruby

Trying to solve this question where you provide arguments and need to provide a matching output.

> Take two integers (i and n) as command line arguments. Write i to standard output, followed by the following n integers (separated by commas).
>
> Do not include spaces or any hidden characters in the output.
>
> > Example: Arguments: 3 5 Output: 3,4,5,6,7,8

Here's my code:

```
base_number = ARGV.shift.to_i
iterate_number = ARGV.shift.to_i

if iterate_number < 0
  base_number = base_number.to_s
  iterate_number = iterate_number.to_s
else
  print base_number
  iterate_number.times do
    base_number = base_number + 1
    print ','
    print base_number
  end
end
```

So far, I've managed to catch 7 / 9 of the tests. This includes when iterate_number is negative, which the output returns blank.

The last two tests involve arguments which are letters or blank, both which resolve in the variable i returning 0, giving my output to be 0 instead of blank.

Thanks!

Comment: A detail: you could write `base_number, iterate_number = ARGV.map(&:to_i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with `times`, but you're missing out on one of the key features in Ruby: Leveraging an Enumerator and treating it like an array.

For example:

```
i = ARGV[0].to_i
n = ARGV[1].to_i

puts (i..i+n).to_a.join(', ')
```

This sets up a simple range, converts it to an array of values, then joins those values together.

If you want to test if a value is "numerical", try this:

```
value.to_i.to_s == value
```

If it's the same when converted to an integer and back it's guaranteed to be an integer value.

Comment: Ah, that makes complete sense! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To check if `i` is a string you can call `i.match(/^\d+$/)`, when it's not a string it'll return `false`

Answer (score -1):

When you say letters or blank, do you mean a `"String"` or ``nil```?

You should check if the input is an integer first.

`return nil unless iterate_number.is_a?(Integer)`